# Does MPI_Send send address of an array or array content

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mpi

I am writing Mergesort with MPI to sort an array of integers. The idea is to mergesort the left half of the array on the same rank, while sending the right half of the array to a child rank. So if there are four procs, it looks like this:

```
                        rank 0, a[0..N]
                      /                  \
      rank 0, a[0..N/2]                      rank1, a[N/2..N]
        /           \                       /               \
rank0, a[0..N/4]   rank2,a[N/4..N/2]   rank1,a[N/2..3N/4]   rank3,a[3N/4..N]
```

The parent rank always sends the unsorted right half of array to right child, receives the sorted subarray back from right child.

In serial mergesort algorithm, the sorting of subarray can be done on the same address of the whole array without generating temp array. Can the same thing be applied to MPI implementation with `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv`? My understanding is `MPI_Send` sends the address of the first element of the subarray

```
//rank == 0
int *a, size1, size2;
getData(a);
size1=size/2;
size2=size-size1;
MPI_Send(a+size1, size2, MPI_INT, seed_rank, DATA, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Child process does seem to get the subarray values by doing the following:

```
//rank == 1
int *array;
array = new int(size);
MPI_Recv(array, size, MPI_INT, parent, DATA, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);                                                     
mergesort_parallel_mpi(array, size, level);
```

rank 1 then will operate merge sort on received subarray elements which is stored at a different address than the original array. Is there a way to receive array address instead since it will be easier to merge the two sorted subarrays if they are in the same block (and this is what serial merge does). I will get error if I do not allocate for a new array in rank 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending an pointer to a memory location would work only if your processes would work on the same physical machine, and that is not a case in distributed processing with MPI, where every process receives a copy of a data that has been sent to it. You should treat every process as it would run on separate machine, therefore it could directly not access any other machines memory.

If you want to process data using shared memory and threads, take a look on [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) API.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think that MPI processes share memory: they don't. The child process can't modify the parent's array directly, because they have completely separate memory spaces (which could, in fact, reside on physically separate computers).